# Why Media Player can't open flv files that created by Opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

I work on a project that recorder keeps the screen and into the FLV file Synopsis recent actions taken on the screen. But my problem is that Media Player and other programs of windows for playing can't play it. I tried download VLC player and it can play it. here my code can someone help me and tell me what I need to change?

thnx!

here my code:

```
//defining
VideoWriter output_cap("output.flv", CV_FOURCC('F', 'L', 'V', '1'), 10,
    cv::Size(dwWidth,dwHeight), true);

//write to video file
    output_cap.write(image1);
```